# Route-based code splitting chunks are not found after building the app only for deeper routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, code-splitting, react-loadable

I'm building a React App using create-react-app, and now I'm struggling with code splitting in it. I'm using react-loadable. Everything was fine in the development environment, but when it's built some chunks on some deeper routes (e.g. /test/2 or /test-a/42) were not loaded because the chunks were not found (404).

This is how I loaded my component using react-loadable

```
.....

const test = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("../test/test"),
  loading: Loading
});
const testdetail = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("../test/testdetail"),
  loading: Loading
});
const testa = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("../test/testa"),
  loading: Loading
});
const testadetail = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("../test/testadetail"),
  loading: Loading
});

.....
```

Here's how I used those components in my routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/test"
    component={test}
    />
   <Route
    path="/test/:id"
    component={testdetail}
    />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/test-a"
    component={testa}
    />
  <Route
    path="/test-a/:id"
    component={testadetail}
    />
</Switch>
```

As I said everything seemed okay in development mode, however the routes `/test/:id` & `/test-a/:id` chunks were not found in production mode after I built the app. Any answer would really save my life, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems okay. Have you tried other libraries like "[loadable-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadable-components)"

. You can also upgrade to CRA-2.0 with new

> React.lazy

and

> Suspense
>   which are also used for code splitting and many other stuffs. Check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting).
>   . 
>   If you are not using SSR then you can try these.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the new lazy function from React, it still didn't work, but I've figured it out that the issue was with the react router https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-work-when-loading-nested-routes , but thanks for the answer.